Pagination Web Scraping
I am trying web scraping a website for Test data. I am stuck at extracting data from all pages, I checked the pagination code from source file, but my code is still returning page one data only. Can anyone help me what I am missing in my code.
Code I am using:
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def navigate_to_next_page():
    try:
        next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.pagination-next a'))
        )
        next_button.click()
        return True
    except:
        return False

def extract_test_data():
    # Find all test divs
    test_divs = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product"))
    )
    # Iterate over each test div to extract test name, URL, and price
    for test_div in test_divs:
        test_link = test_div.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.text-theme-colored")
        test_name = test_link.text.strip()
        test_url = test_link.get_attribute("href")  # Extract href attribute for URL
        test_price = test_div.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.amount").text.strip()
        # Append test data to the list
        all_test_data.append([test_url, test_name, test_price])

base_url = "https://www.tenetdiagnostics.in/book/tests?type=p"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get(base_url)


all_test_data = []

while True:
    extract_test_data()
    if not navigate_to_next_page():
        break

csv_file = "tenet_test_data.csv"
with open(csv_file, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Test URL", "Test Name", "Test Price"])  # Write header
    writer.writerows(all_test_data)

print("Test data saved to", csv_file)

driver.quit()


This code is giving me desired results but only from first page. I want to extract data from all pages.
Thanks In Advance!

you have catchall exception handling on navigation_to_next_page(). Print out the exception to console and see whats the issue you are getting ?

You can use their pagination Ajax API to load the data, e.g.:
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "https://infinity.tenetdiagnostics.in/GetServices"

payload = {
    "test_name": "",
    "test_type": "",
    "condition_id": "",
    "speciality_id": "",
    "category_type": "p",
    "sort_by": "",
    "sort_order": "",
    "organ_id": "",
    "city_name": "Hyderabad",
    "from": "10",
    "to": "18",
    "is_popular": "",
}

all_data = []
for i in range(3):
    print("Page", i)

    payload["from"] = i * 9 + 1
    payload["to"] = (i + 1) * 9

    data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()
    all_data.extend(data["data"])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)

Prints:
    ROW  tid                                                        test_name test_code                                                 test_other_names                             service_url  test_price  test_discpr  test_finalpr type parameter_count specimen  is_home_collection website_order test_cdn is_popular department_name   location  gender
0     1    1                                 1, 25-Dihydroxy Vitamin D, Serum   TNT0001                                 1, 25-Dihydroxy Vitamin D, Serum                vitamin-d-1-25-dihydroxy      2190.0            0        2190.0    0               2     None                   1             1  REGULAR          N       Pathology  Hyderabad       4
1     2    2                        17 - Hydroxycorticosteroids, 24 Hrs Urine   TNT0002                        17 - Hydroxycorticosteroids, 24 Hrs Urine               17-hydroxycorticosteroids      4100.0            0        4100.0    0               0     None                   2             1  REGULAR          N       Pathology  Hyderabad       4
2     3    3                         17 - Hydroxyprogesterone (17-OHP), Serum   TNT0003                         17 - Hydroxyprogesterone (17-OHP), Serum                  17-hydroxyprogesterone      1610.0            0        1610.0    0               1     None                   1             1  REGULAR          N       Pathology  Hyderabad       4
3     4    4                                    17 Ketosteroids, 24 Hrs Urine   TNT0004                                    17 Ketosteroids, 24 Hrs Urine                         17-ketosteroids      3570.0            0        3570.0    0               2     None                   2             1  REGULAR          N       Pathology  Hyderabad       4
4     5    5                                    25 - Hydroxy Vitamin D, Serum   TNT0005                                    25 - Hydroxy Vitamin D, Serum                    25-hydroxy-vitamin-d      1990.0            0        1990.0    0               2     None                   1             1  REGULAR          N       Pathology  Hyderabad       4

...

